# Failed to stop Apache Spark Master or Slave using Systemd

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, systemd, systemctl, init.d

## Perspectives

---

Actually I needs to configure two service files. One for **Spark Master** and another for **Spark Slave (Worker)** node. Please find the environment and service configuration as following:

## Cofigurations

---

#### `/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/env`

---

```bash
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
SPARK_HOME="/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3"
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"
```

#### `/etc/systemd/system/spark-master.service`

---

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Apache Spark Master
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=spark
Group=spark
Type=forking

WorkingDirectory=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin
EnvironmentFile=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/env
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "echo $MAINPID > /opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/spark-master.pid"
ExecStart=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-master.sh
ExecStop=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/stop-master.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### `/etc/systemd/system/spark-slave.service`

---

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Apache Spark Slave
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=spark
Group=spark
Type=forking

WorkingDirectory=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin
EnvironmentFile=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/env
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "echo $MAINPID > /opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/spark-slave.pid"
ExecStart=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://spark.cdn.chorke.org:7077
ExecStop=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/stop-slave.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## Outcome

---

It's started successfully but failed to stop successfully for some sorts of errors! Actually it's failed to stop Apache Spark Master or Slave using Systemd

#### Spark Master Stop Status

---

```
× spark-master.service - Apache Spark Master
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/spark-master.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-09-26 18:43:39 +08; 8s ago
       Docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0
    Process: 488887 ExecStart=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-master.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 489000 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c echo $MAINPID > /opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/spark-master.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 489484 ExecStop=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/stop-master.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 488903 (code=exited, status=143)
        CPU: 4.813s
```

#### Spark Slave Stop Status

---

```
× spark-slave.service - Apache Spark Slave
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/spark-slave.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-09-26 18:38:22 +08; 15s ago
       Docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0
    Process: 489024 ExecStart=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://ns12-pc04:7077 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 489145 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c echo $MAINPID > /opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/spark-slave.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 489174 ExecStop=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/stop-slave.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 489040 (code=exited, status=143)
        CPU: 4.306s
```

## Expected Behavior

---

Your guide line would be appreciated to shutdown both Master & Slave node without any error.

Comment: Following links might be helpful to pass `systemctl` exit unit test [Service Exit Code Unit Test Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953678) & [Services remain in failed state after stopped with systemctl](https://serverfault.com/questions/695849/)

Comment: ```[Service]
SuccessExitStatus=143```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Theoretical Solution

---

In this case you have to write your own script for manipulating the shutdown to force exit code `0` instead of `143`. If you are idle enough like me then you can change`SuccessExitStatus` from `0` to `143`. By default `systemd` unit test looking for`SuccessExitStatus` code is 0. We need to change the default unit test behavior.

## Practical Solution

---

### `/etc/systemd/system/spark-master.service`

---

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Apache Spark Master
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=spark
Group=spark
Type=forking
SuccessExitStatus=143

WorkingDirectory=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin
EnvironmentFile=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/env
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "echo $MAINPID > /opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/spark-master.pid"
ExecStart=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-master.sh
ExecStop=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/stop-master.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### `/etc/systemd/system/spark-slave.service`

---

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Apache Spark Slave
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=spark
Group=spark
Type=forking
SuccessExitStatus=143

WorkingDirectory=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin
EnvironmentFile=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/env
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "echo $MAINPID > /opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/etc/spark-slave.pid"
ExecStart=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://spark.cdn.chorke.org:7077
ExecStop=/opt/cli/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/sbin/stop-slave.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```